# Does Visual Studio 2005 error C1083 ("Not enough space") mean I ran out of RAM?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, build, build-error

I've received this Visual Studio error.  Though I can figure out the jist of the problem, I don't totally understand because I don't know much about the build process.  What is the real problem here and what are some potential solutions?

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler intermediate file: 
'C:\libpath\libname.lib': Not enough space
LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed

Error executing link.exe (tool returned code: 1257)
```

I get "not enough space", but I don't really understand what that means.  What kind of space does it need to build?  Is this saying it ran out of RAM? How could this potentially be solved?

Note: the solution this is trying to build is huge

Comment: know it sounds silly but do you have enough Hard drive space. Google Chrome Source code is only ~450MB but requires IIRC 10GB of free space to build. VS does create tons of pdb objs and what nots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 9/28/2019** Since MS Connect has been retired, the previous link is now dead.

I was able to dig up this via google and pasting here for posterity:

> This out-of-memory issue has been fixed in VS 2010. I tried the provided
>    link repro on a 32-bit Win7 (x86) machine, and the linking finished successfully
>   , with virtual memory usage peaked at about 1.6GB. Please try VS 2010.
>    If you need a hotfix of this issue for an old-versioned VS, 
>   please contact Microsoft PSS.

---

This seems to be a bug. See this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/581207/visual-studio-2005-sp1-reproducible-linker-error-lkn1257-caused-by-c1083

Unfortunately, the solution isn't that pleasing (unless you can upgrade to VS 2010).

An alternative would be to switch to MSBuild or Nant that you can run outside of VS 2005 process (you can map a shortcut to these tools so that you can trigger the build within VS 2005).

Comment: What was the solution? The link is dead.

Comment: @KunalTyagi The solution was already in my answer (upgrading to VS 2010) but I can see how it may not have been clear. Anyway, I edited my post to make things clearer.

Comment: Thanks. It's just that a similar issue came up in MSVC 2017 but during linking :)